# how can i build a simply backend managable website without using CMS like wordpress?

Tags: backend, webflow

i want to build a website with a backend that even a highschool student can edit(images, text etc). I tried considering WEBFLOW but its subscription plan is too high annually. I have used wordpress for a long time & I am conversant with page builders & have knowledge of html & css. I tried using webflow, it works best but problem is subscription & limitations

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow, please check out [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).